# Php script not getting correct value in android

Tags: java, php, android, webview

Im creating an android app using webview and php. i wrote a php to get the value of the user logged in(0 if no ones logged in) if the users logged in(through the app ofcourse) i need to change the icons of the option menu and if no user is logged in the icons would be different. However the php script is not getting the correct value in android but its working fine when i open it from a computer and test by logging in and out of the website

here's the code for options menu that calls isloggedin() function

```
register=omenu.findItem(R.id.registeraccount);
    login=omenu.findItem(R.id.loginitem);

    String checklogin= isloggedin();
    Toast.makeText(this, checklogin, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(!checklogin.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
    {
        register.setIcon(R.drawable.account);
        register.setTitle("Account");
        login.setIcon(R.drawable.logout);
        login.setTitle("Logout");
    }
    else{
        register.setIcon(R.drawable.register);
        register.setTitle("Register");
        login.setIcon(R.drawable.login);
        login.setTitle("Login");

    }
```

the isloggedin() function

```
 public String isloggedin()
{


    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url/checklogin.php");

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

       final String response = httpclient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
        return  response;

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "";

    }

}
```

and then i've also called the invalidateoptionsmenu() on the webviewclient's onpagefinished() method so that the optionsmenu can be recreated and update the icons if required

```
loadsite.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.loadUrl(url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();


            }
        });
        ;
        loadsite.loadUrl("url");
```

the php script executed through the isloggedin() function always returns 0 whether the user is signed in or not. however when i sign in from a laptop the script returns 1 or any othe value other than 0 to indicate which user is logged in

the php script

```
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$id=$current_user->ID
echo $id
```